# Sinclair Lewis' It Can't Happen

Tags: meaning

Can someone explain to me in the following passage (bold type):

> "Being a person who read little and therefore took what he did read seriously, Buck was distressed by the **normally studious Lorinda’s vacation liking** for novels about distressed princesses, and when she airily insisted that they were better guides to conduct than Anthony Trollope or Thomas Hardy, Buck roared at her and in the feebleness of **baited strength**, nervously filled pipes and knocked them out against the stone mantel."

I don't know what *vacation* and *baited* mean in this context.

Comment: She had a liking for those novels only when on vacation. To subdue his annoyance, he tempered his strength with nervous activity. Thus, he withheld and baited his strength. (Bait here is unrelated to fishing with bait.)

Comment: @YosefBaskin It's unrelated because it's mistranscribed. The word is *bate*; *bait* is the wrong homonym.

Comment: Lorinda normally read more serious books, which Buck considered fitting. But in the vacations, she let down her hair and read frivolous fantasy novels. // frustrated, tormented.

Comment: 'Baited' may be correct in the sense that Lorinda is deliberately antagonising Buck with her statements on reading preference. He seems an easy mark for that kind of baiting.

Comment: Cassio, are you able to tell us if the spelling of 'baited' we have here is correct?

Comment: @DJClayworth Then it wouldn't modify *strength*, and the *feebleness* would be completely unanchored. The intended word is *bated*, unequivocally. Someone somewhere along the line misspelled it. It might have even have been the original author.

Comment: [https://ebooks.adelaide.edu.au/l/lewis/sinclair/happen/chapter16.html] It does indeed seem to be the original author--or his editor.

Comment: Never a safe call to say a Nobel Laureate was wrong.

Comment: @DJClayworth It is safe when [the Nobel Laureates are objectively wrong](http://news.nationalgeographic.com/2015/10/151005-nobel-laureates-forget-racist-sexist-science/).

Comment: Big difference between 'did something immoral' and 'used the wrong word'. (And it would be pushing a philosophical point to say that any immorality is *objectively* wrong). But more importantly, literary masters often use deliberately ungrammatical or misspelled words for effect.

Comment: Hello everyone. First, tank you so much for all your comments. The meaning of "vacation" here is pretty clear to me now. As for "baited", the word is correct (page 143, Penguin's Signet Classics, brochure, '14 printing). I thought it could be "bated" too but to be sure ought see other (older) editions. (As you can see, my english is not very good, please correct me when see fit.)